# Does De Bruijn–Erdős implies Ultrafilter Lemma?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, set-theory

The [De Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)) may be proven using Ultrafilter Lemma, for example by using Consistancy Principle which states that every binary mess has a map compatible with it.

My question is whether or not this theorem is equivalent to the $UL$. I tried to find either a proof of it using something weaker than $UL$ or at least a proof of some set theoretical fact from De Bruijn–Erdős theorem that is known to be independent to $ZF$ as a warmup, but I failed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: From the wikipedia page you linked, "the De Bruijn–Erdős theorem and the Boolean prime ideal theorem are equivalent in axiomatic power". The boolean prime ideal theorem is equivalent to the ultrafilter lemma.

Comment: Oh you're correct, that is a little bit awkward but you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot access the Lauchli paper referenced by the wikipedia page. But I do remember this is given as exercise 2.24 in Jech's book "The Axiom of Choice". In fact, you can show that the seemingly weaker statement

> for every graph $G$, if every finite subgraph of $G$ is 3-colorable, then $G$ is 3-colorable

implies the boolean prime ideal theorem. One way to show this is to do something similar to the way you reduce SAT to 3COL in complexity theory. Here is a [link](http://cs.bme.hu/thalg/3sat-to-3col.pdf), maybe I'll leave the details to you.